# Clone several git repositories using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to clone several git repositories at the same time. But my script seems to be not working correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a git_resources=("https://git.polarsys.org/c/capella/capella.git"  "https://github.com/mbats/mindstorms")

if [ ! -d "$HOME"/git ]; then
    mkdir "$HOME"/git
fi

cd "$HOME"/git || { printf "cd failed, exiting\n" >&2;  return 1; }

for i in ${git_resources[@]} ; do
 echo  $i


done
```

what is returned is : `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` .

is there any problem in the way how I declared the list of strings ?

Comment: And where is problem? Please post expected result.

Comment: Main problem: your script doesn't attempt to clone any git respositories. Minor problem: Using `return` like that will fail and the for loop will execute even if the git directory doesn't exist.

Comment: What's the meaning of "not working correctly"?

Comment: I mean not returning the expected result

Comment: I encourage you to narrow down the problem to something even smaller. Perhaps just declare a list of strings without doing anything to them. See if you can get that working first before introducing anything about git or directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> ```

This is an sh script. Sh doesn't have arrays or a `declare` builtin. Since you want to write in bash, start your script with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

---

> ```
> cd "$HOME"/git || …
> ```

Instead of handling each error individually — and only when you remember to do it — put `set -e` at the beginning of the script so that it will stop on an error.

---

> ```
> for i in ${git_resources[@]} ; do
>  echo  $i
> ```

[Always use double quotes around variable expansions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) unless you know why you need to leave them out. This applies even when expanding an array: `${git_resources[@]}` splits and globs individual array elements. You need `"${git_resources[@]}"` to get the list of array elements.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

declare -a git_resources=(
    "https://git.polarsys.org/c/capella/capella.git"  
    "https://github.com/mbats/mindstorms"
)

if [ ! -d "$HOME"/git ]; then
    mkdir "$HOME"/git
fi
cd "$HOME"/git

for url in "${git_resources[@]}"; do
    dir="${url##*/}"
    dir="${dir%.git}"
    if [ -e "$dir/.git" ]; then
        git -C "$dir" update
    else
        git clone "$url"
    fi
done
```